# run a if step by step PHP

Tags: php

i have a problem in PHP, i want first show a message like this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

and when i clicked on ok, then redirect to another page, my code is like this:

```
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home2.php");
```

complete code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{ 
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home2.php");
}
```

but this code do not show me the message just redirect to home2.php, if there is another way except of 'if' please explain. the simplest way 
thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it showed the alert message..

Comment: You need to perform the redirect in javascript.

Comment: @FirasRassas How could you try his code, when you dont know what the `RedirecttoUrl` method does?

Comment: @FirasRassas: $fgmembersite is included by functions, not important, replace that line by your way that can connect to another page. i just need rn two line step by step, first message and then redirect to another page

Comment: Odds are your redirect function in PHP is taking place before the DOM is complete on the clients side, so the alert is actually never even sent to the user.

Comment: @Steve: how? can u explain? 
like this?

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{ 
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home2.php");
echo '</script>';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to redirect to another page.. you can do this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<script>window.location.href = "the-target-page.php";</script>';
```

Comment: please vote my ask, my reputation is below 13, i need 15 to vote answers :)

Comment: can u solve my new problem? here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254240/make-a-favorite-list-of-job-using-php-and-mysql/33254942?noredirect=1#comment54315491_33254942

Answer (score 1):

you should use javascript o redirect only. You are trying to mix, both php and javascript

```
echo "<script>javascript:alert('message successfully sent'); window.location = 'home2.php'</script>";
```

Comment: can u solve my new problem? here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254240/make-a-favorite-list-of-job-using-php-and-mysql/33254942?noredirect=1#comment54315491_33254942