# make a favorite list of job using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database in my php page that included by: 
name, family, phone_number, job, username and password 
here is my code to select all job list:

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'tablesite';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  $db_table WHERE job<>''",$con);
while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
echo "* name: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]."   ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."* job: ".$amch["job"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."* phone_number: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."* email: ".$amch["email"].'<br>';
}
?>
```

so i fetched all people that has a job, i need a favorite list, i mean when a user log in, can add some people to him/her favorite list, and the favorite list must be different than other user.

this is my login page:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
  if($fgmembersite->Login())
 {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home2.php");
}
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Login</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style/fg_membersite.css"/>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'>    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<div id='fg_membersite'>
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>ورود</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<div class='short_explanation' dir="rtl">فیلدهای الزامی *</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container' dir="rtl">
     <label for='username' >:نام کاربری *</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container' dir="rtl">
    <label for='password' >:کلمه عبور *</label><br/>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='ورود' />
<!-- </div>
<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
</fieldset> -->
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("login");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

    frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide your username");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide the password");

// ]]>
</script>
</div>
<!--
Form Code End (see html-form-guide.com for more info.)
-->

</body>
```

do i need a new db? or i can use of my current db with some more fields? use of foreign keys?

note: membersite_config.php is included by: db name, table name, host name, username and password. 
it should act like a shopping cart, when a user want buy a thing first should login and then can add goods to him/her cart and also can remove items after adding them but here we need add users instead of goods 
tahanks...

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a new table here. You can make a table in this way :-

Table name :- **favouriters**

```
indexid int(11) not null auto_increment,
username varchar(255) not null,
favourites varchar(255) not null
```

I've used `indexid` as an auto-increment column to make searching and deleting from the table much faster.

`username` is the common key between your users table and your *Favourites* table. You can connect both of them via this key.

Now here comes the major part, in this `favourites` column, you'll add the user's favourite members in a comma separated way. Like this.

```
favouriteuser1, favouriteuser2, favouriteuser3
```

Now, you can easily access all the favourite users of all the users. In this way, you can easily add a new username in the above list, or can remove a username from the above list.

You can use a simple `LEFT JOIN` to get the table data.

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN favourites USING(username);
```

Comment: i want add favorites via a button. in fact each user can have some favorite, i think your way is manual and cant add users automatically. and what is code of favouriteuser1, favouriteuser2, favouriteuser3? please explain more by code

Comment: it should act like a shopping cart, when a user want buy a thing first should login and then can add goods to him/her cart and also can remove items after adding them, i think it is more clearly

Comment: Favorites is different and shopping cart is different. What do you actually need?

Comment: i want a same way of shopping, adding favorite people in user account that can view later by own user. as we can add items for buying, we add users the same way. i dont want add favorite people myself, i want let to users add them favorites buy themself. did u got know?

Comment: *name= irana  *family= sohrabi *job=dr  *phone_nember=? button add to favrorite

*name= jason  *family= rezaeeyan *job=?  *phone_nember=? button add to favrorite